# SwipeDismissTouchListener Calls onClickListener after Swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch, swipe, swipe-gesture

in the `touchListener` below `View`'s onClick method is called even after a swipe gesture is detected. (no matter left or right)

I've already tried returning true in the end but it blocks the normal clicks from happening as well

```
public class SwipeDismissTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private int mSlop;
private int mMinFlingVelocity;
private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
private long mAnimationTime;

private View mView;
private View mBackground;
private TextView mBackgroundText;
private OnDismissCallback mCallback;
private int mViewWidth = 1;

private float mDownX;
private boolean mSwiping;
private Object mToken;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private float mTranslationX;

public interface OnDismissCallback {
    void onDismiss(View view, Object token);

    void onRightSwipe(View view);

    void onLeftSwipe(View view);
}

public SwipeDismissTouchListener(View view, View BackgroundContainer, TextView tvBg, Object token, OnDismissCallback callback) {
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(view.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mAnimationTime = view.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    mView = view;
    mToken = token;
    mCallback = callback;
    mBackground = BackgroundContainer;
    mBackgroundText = tvBg;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    motionEvent.offsetLocation(mTranslationX, 0);

    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            final float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            float velocityX = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
            float velocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean dismiss = false;
            boolean dismissRight = false;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 3 * 2) {
                dismiss = true;
                dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= velocityX && velocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                    && velocityY < velocityX) {
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 5) {
                    dismiss = true;
                    dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }
            }
            if (dismiss) {
                mView.animate()
                        .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                        .alpha(0)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                if (deltaX > 0) {
                                    mCallback.onRightSwipe(mView);
                                } else {
                                    mCallback.onLeftSwipe(mView);
                                }
                                mView.setX(0);
                                mView.animate()
                                        .alpha(1)
                                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                                        .setListener(null);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                mView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
            }
                           mVelocityTracker = null;
            mTranslationX = 0;
            mDownX = 0;
            mSwiping = false;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                mSwiping = true;

                mView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                mView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
            }

            if (mSwiping) {
                mTranslationX = deltaX;
                mView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    mBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BD362F"));
                    mBackgroundText.setText("رد درخواست");
                } else {
                    mBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#51A361"));
                    mBackgroundText.setText("تایید درخواست");
                }
                mView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                        1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX / 3 * 2) / mViewWidth)));
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void performDismiss() {
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
    final int originalHeight = mView.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCallback.onDismiss(mView, mToken);
            mView.setAlpha(1f);
            mView.setTranslationX(0);
            lp.height = originalHeight;
            mView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            mView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
}}
```

and the listener is applied to a `Recyclerview` row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the end of action up event to return true if a swipe is detected

```
if (mSwiping) {
     mSwiping = false;
     return true;
}
mSwiping = false;
```